# Settings in 'Media > Settings' is ignored when inserting images

Tags: uploads, media, thumbnails, images

When I upload an image, it is automatically resized as I would expect, however the sizes for inserting the image seem to ignore the settings I've placed in Settings/Media.

In my media settings I have:

- Thumbnail: 150 x 150
- Medium: 300 x 300
- Large: 690 x 9999

I upload an image of: *2226 x 1663*.
Wordpress generates the correct image sizes, but gives me the following options for insertion:

- Thumbnail: 150 x 150 (as expected)
- Medium: 300 x 224 (as expected)
- Large: 640 x 447 (Wrong. Why?)

I looked on the forums and found a suggestion that I add the following to my functions.php file:

```
update_option('large_size_w', 690);
```

However, this did not work.

Comment: On further investigation, it appears Wordpress *is* resizing the image correctly, to 690 x 515 - however it is still inserting the image at 640 x 447 using the width and height parameters of the IMG tag.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to revise the title and description to reflect this discovery?

Comment: Also: What **Theme** is currently active. (If not Twenty Eleven, please switch to Twenty Eleven, regenerate Thumbnails if necessary, and verify if you still observe the same behavior.) And do you have any **Plugins** active that interact with image functionality?

Comment: I switched this to Twenty Eleven and the sizes were all different. Presumably then, something in my theme (or more likely, the base theme on which it is running, since mine is a child theme of the 'Boilerplate' theme) is setting the large image to 640.
Does anyone know what setting I would be searching for to find this?

Comment: Which "Boilerplate" Theme are you using (there are more than one). Can you link to it, so we can have a poke around?

Comment: Indeed I can:
http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/download/boilerplate.3.4.4.zip

Comment: Okay, and just to be double-sure: when you're using Twenty Eleven, and change your Thumbnail/Medium/Large image dimensions via `Settings -> Media`, your custom-defined sizes appear in the insert-image modal window?

Comment: Ahh... actually, no. The sizes in the modal window change, but they still do not match those in media > settings.

I'd be happy enough hardcoding them in my theme though.

Comment: And let me guess: in Twenty Eleven, the Large image size is constrained to a width of **584px**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe your issue is that the value set for the global **`$content_width`** variable (which is **640px** in Boilerplate and **584px** in Twenty Eleven) is less than the width you're specifying via `Settings -> Media`.

WordPress is overriding your user setting with the Theme-specific value. This actually makes sense, since a Theme knows its maximum content width, and using a larger image width than what the Theme is designed to accommodate would very likely break the Theme layout.

The solution, then, if you need to change the large image width to **690px** (and assuming your Child Theme can accommodate this width), is to **define `$content_width` in your Child Theme `functions.php` file**. I would recommend using a Child Theme setup function, hooked into `after_setup_theme()`, like so:

```
<?php
function wpse48075_theme_setup() {
    // Define $content_width global
    global $content_width;
    if ( ! isset( $content_width ) ) {
        $content_width = 690;
    }
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse48075_theme_setup', 9 );
?>
```

The priority **9** is probably overkill, since your Child Theme's actions will be added before the parent Theme's actions anyway; but using priority 9 will guarantee that this action fires before the parent Theme setup fires, at priority 10.

Since your Child Theme action fires first, the Child Theme defines `$content_width`, and the Parent Theme does not override it (since it also uses a `if ( ! isset() )` conditional wrapper).

#### Edit

So, looking at the Twenty Eleven `functions.php` file, I realized I made a bad assumption: Twenty Eleven defines `$content_width` nakedly in `functions.php`, rather than inside the Theme setup function, hooked into `after_setup_theme`. So, to override it, ** you have to do likewise**.

Just put the following at the top of your `functions.php` file, before any other function definitions:

```
$content_width = 690;
```

This should work, since the Child Theme `functions.php` gets parsed before the Parent Theme `functions.php`.

(This is a prime example of why Themes should **wrap all the things inside callbacks**. :) )

Comment: Excellent, thanks for your help. I'll give that a try.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work either... I don't know enough about Wordpress really offer any suggestions as to why, this looked like it would work fine.
Any ideas?

Comment: You never answered my question above: "*And let me guess: in Twenty Eleven, the Large image size is constrained to a width of **584px**?*" Is that the case?

Comment: It is, yes... That's why I thought your suggestion would work! ;)

Comment: See updated answer. :)

Comment: Haha wow this seems like a total failure for Wordpress. If the theme wants to limit the dimensions of images, Wordpress should actually correctly resize the image down instead of leaving it at a larger size (which wastes bandwidth) and [returning the wrong image dimensions](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/167525) in `wp_get_attachment_image_src()`. Also [the docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) mention nothing about this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more control on what image sizes are generated when you upload images, have a look at the [Simple Image Sizes plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-image-sizes/)

Answer (score 0):

Modify your settings on the media page so that your maximum embed width is 690 rather than blank

[image]

Comment: I've already done this to no avail.