# wp_get_attachment_image_src() returning incorrect width and height

Tags: images

I am trying to return the src, width and height of a cetain image:

```
$img = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large');
```

This is returning the expected array but with incorrect width and height values

```
$img[0] -> .../wp-content/uploads/2014/11/image-2000x1125.jpg
$img[1] -> 640
$img[2] -> 360
```

The image is actually 2000x1125 but the width and height returned are incorrect.
I have tried regenerating sizes with several plugins with no luck. This issue happens only with 'large' size.

Could this be a bug?
Is there some other way of returning image sizes (hopefully correct)?

Comment: If you want to return the original uploaded file, use `full` instead of `large`

Comment: I want to retrieve each of the available sizes. And I already have achieved, but have a bug with large size only, in all images Ive tried so far (640 as width and different height, always incorrect)

Comment: Did you changed sizes in Settings -> Media?

Comment: I changed long time ago, if I upload a new image right now, it keeps returning 640..

Answer (score 1):

I found the same issue here and the solution from there works: [Settings in 'Media > Settings' is ignored when inserting images](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48075/settings-in-media-settings-is-ignored-when-inserting-images)

The solution is as simple as paste this:

```
$content_width = 2000;// The value I want
```

in functions.php

Explanation copied from there(user Chip Bennett):

I believe your issue is that the value set for the global $content_width variable (which is 640px in Boilerplate and 584px in Twenty Eleven) is less than the width you're specifying via Settings -> Media.

WordPress is overriding your user setting with the Theme-specific value. This actually makes sense, since a Theme knows its maximum content width, and using a larger image width than what the Theme is designed to accommodate would very likely break the Theme layout.